# Cannot make filter on rich:datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, richdatatable

I am working on a project and there are some parts which I have not developed. Right now I have to set a filter on a table, as we use rich faces, I wanted to use the filter as in the example from [exadel](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?c=filtering).

However it doesn't work, I know it may be due to the `filterValue` property, because I am not sure if I am pointing to the proper bean. Everything looks good but the filter is not there.

Any suggestions? How can I get to know what is the proper bean? 
This contains only the column that I want to filter.

```
<rich:dataTable var="_project"
    value="#{projectController.showDeactivateEmployees? projects : projectController.getViewableProjects(projects)}"
    rendered="#{not empty projectController.getViewableProjects(projects)}"
    styleClass="simpletablestyle" sortMode="single">
    <rich:column filterBy="#{_project.name}" filterValue="#{project.name}">
            <f:facet name="header">#{msg.common_Name}</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{_project.name}"
                style="color:#{_project.usedHours * 100 / _project.maxHours &gt;= 75 and _project.maxHours!=0? '#d20f19' : '#000000'};">
            </h:outputText>
    </rich:column>
<rich:datatable/>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The attribute name is just "filterValue".</strike>

What is proper bean is up to you, `filterValue` just has to point to some property where you want the value to be stored.

Comment: Thanks for the point, but that was just miss spelled on this post, I had it right on my code...

Comment: I wonder how that happens. I've updated the answer, what's the scope of the bean you are saving the value in?